# Session not transferring over to next requests

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm finally learning how to use class and `__init__`, however I'm having an issue with `session`. It seems like `session` is not carrying over to the next request. I made a simple script for testing, it adds an item, then I make another request to see if the Bag contains any value (eg. Bag(1)). The problem is that the item is adding but I'm getting Bag(0) when I make the second request. All I can think of is that there might be an issue with `session` on my part, but I can't figure it out. Here's the script:

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Test():

    def __init__(self):
        self.s = requests.Session()
        self.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.98 Safari/537.36'

    def cart(self):
        headers = {'User-Agent': self.userAgent}
        r = self.s.get('http://undefeated.com/store/index.php?api=1&rowid=130007&qty=1', headers=headers)
        print(r.text)
        if re.findall('Added', r.text):
            r = self.s.get('http://undefeated.com/store/cart/pg', headers=headers).text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')
            bag = soup.find('li', {'class': 'leaf cart'}).text
            print(bag)

start = Test().cart()
```

Comment: I just tried this in a browser and it doesn't seem to work there either. So I don't think your code is the problem - or, at least, not the only problem. Something on the _server_ is not doing what you expect it to do. BTW, if you're doing this to learn about classes and object-oriented programming in Python, I'd advise against dealing with networking. There are plenty of OOP applications you can do without having to use the internet (which comes with its own set of complications).

Comment: I have figured it out, I needed to add proper request header for session to work.